# How to play three specific mp3 files in a webpage

Tags: jquery, file, mp3

I need to find a plugin ( jquery if possible )  which can play three different files ( the three files are not always the same; the name of the three files I want to play were generated with a query result.

The plugin MUST WORK with IE 8.

Comment: As the downvote tooltip says: "this question does not show any research effort".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "play 3 mp3 files"? Do you want them to play automatically? Are they supposed to play in a specific order or simultaneously?

Comment: @NullUserException  play automatically, and I reapeat , its NOT alway the same file in the SAME page , its very important , I get the file name with a Mysql Querry

Answer (score 3):

Uhm, not to be one of those "did you google it first" people, but....

- [Sound Manager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)
- [Nifty PLayer](http://www.varal.org/niftyplayer/)
- [jmp3](http://www.sean-o.com/jquery/jmp3/)
- [1 bit audio player](http://1bit.markwheeler.net/)

The list continues. there are a lot of open-source, javascript-controllable mp3/audio players out there.